# Wechat Miniprogram: How to display local image with <img> tag?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

The standard `<image>` tag works fine with a local image:

```
<image src="../../data/pics/1001.png"></image>
```

The tag `<rich-text>` works fine with remote images:

```
<rich-text nodes='<img src="http://images.kaishiba.com/o_1cs1glier2lsdge1q9irbs1a5u4e.jpg">'
></rich-text>
```

But the `<rich-text>` tag doesn't work anymore with my local image:

```
<rich-text nodes='<img src="../../data/pics/1001.png">'
></rich-text>
```

I just get a little empty square on the screen.

From the official documentation [here](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/component/rich-text.html?t=19042820), it is supposed to be supported.

Is there something wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the [Bug & Tip](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/component/rich-text.html) section :

> 6. tip: img label only supports network images.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me with local path in .wxml file. I set the variable .js file and called that for path. It works with normal string as well.

But in .wxss file, it didn't work as background-image url. Here it works with network images only. 
**.js code**

```
data: { 
    profileImg: '../../media/profilePic1.png'
  }
```

**.wxml code. called above**

```
<image class="userinfo-avatar" src="{{profileImg}}" mode="cover"></image>
```

**.wxss file code didn't work for local image path**

```
.bg
{
background-image: url('../../media/profilePic1.png');
}
```